# How to attach mssql database using relative path?

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry if this's been already asked! 
I am able to attach a mssql database on button click using this code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true")) 
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", connection))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("", connection))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE [TRTF_TagLogging] ON (FILENAME ='C:\\Release\\App_Data\\TRTF_TagLogging.mdf'),(FILENAME ='C:\\Release\\App_Data\\App_Data\\TRTF_TagLogging_log.ldf') FOR ATTACH";

                            cmd1.CommandText = "if(exists(select * from sys.databases where name = 'TRTF_TagLogging')) PRINT 'DB attached'";

                            connection.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            //the rest of the code
```

I would like to be able to attach the db using a relative path. Meaning that instead of using 'C:\Release\App_Data\TRTF_TagLogging.mdf', I should use '.\App_Data\TRTF_TagLogging.mdf'.
Using '.\App_Data\TRTF_TagLogging.mdf', I get `'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A file activation error occurred. The physical file name '.\App_Data\TRTF_TagLogging.mdf' may be incorrect.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is interested, I managed to solve it like this:

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE DATABASE [TRTF_TagLogging] ON (FILENAME ='" + path + @"\App_Data\TRTF_TagLogging.mdf'),(FILENAME ='" + path + @"\App_Data\TRTF_TagLogging_log.ldf') FOR ATTACH";
```

`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns, in my case, C:\Release.